# The name 'winner' is not defined

Tags: python

I am building a rock paper scissors game which can store the number of wins of the player and computer. But i am getting this error **name 'winner' is not defined** on line 53. How do i fix it? I even tried to define the winner name at the top of the code but still it would say that the name 'winner' is not defined.

```
    import random

while True:

    player_winnings = 0
    computer_winnings = 0

    choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
    player_choice = input("Please enter your choice: ")
    comp_choice = random.choice(choices)
    print(comp_choice)



    if (player_choice == "Rock") and (comp_choice == "Paper"):
        print("Computer Won!")
        computer_winnings += 1
    if (player_choice == "Paper") and (comp_choice == "Paper"):
        print("Tie.")
    if (player_choice == "Scissor") and (comp_choice == "Paper"):
        print("You Won!")
        player_winnings += 1

    if (player_choice == "Scissors") and (comp_choice == "Rock"):
        print("Computer Won!")
        computer_winnings += 1
    if (player_choice == "Rock") and (comp_choice == "Rock"):
        print("Tie.")
    if (player_choice == "Paper") and (comp_choice == "Rock"):
        print("You Won!")
        player_winnings += 1

    if (player_choice == "Paper") and (comp_choice == "Scissors"):
        print("Computer Won!")
        computer_winnings += 1
    if (player_choice == "Scissors") and (comp_choice == "Scissors"):
        print("Tie.")
    if (player_choice == "Rock") and (comp_choice == "Scissors"):
        print("You Won!")
        player_winnings += 1

    if computer_winnings > player_winnings:
        winner = computer
    elif player_winnings > computer_winnings:
        winner = player
    player_winnings = str(player_winnings)
    computer_winnings = str(computer_winnings)

    exit_choice = input("Do you want to continue. If yes enter Y or y. If no enter N or n. Caution : If you press n or N then your progress will be lost.")
    if exit_choice == 'n' or 'N':
        print("Your winnings are = " + player_winnings)
        print("Computer winnings are = " + computer_winnings)
        print("The winner of this match is" + winner)
        break
    elif exit_choice == 'Y' or exit_choice == 'y':
        continue
```

Comment: What if the winnings are equal?

Comment: There is also the `if var == 5 or 7` kind of problem in checking `exit_choice` against "no". see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true). Also, `computer` and `player` are not defined.

Comment: You defined the `winner` inside `if` scope define it inside `while`'s scope ...

Answer (score 1):

I think when `computer_winnings == player_winnings`, then winner is not defined. 
Thus, initialize `winner` as `None` before `if computer_winnings > player_winnings:`

```
winner = None
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing the variable winner to variables because you are not using strings when you say `winner = computer` or `winner = player`.

Both `computer` and `player` are strings. As such, `winner` should be defined as `winner = 'computer'` or `winner = 'player'`.